# How to decide to cuttoff frequecies of filter in case of using ADC( Flow: Analog-signal to ADC to bits to fir_filter to filtered_output)

Tags: adc, filter, digital-filter, signal-to-noise, fir

1. FIR filter has to be used for removing the noise. I don't know the frequencies of the noise that might be adding up into the analog feedback signal I am taking.
2. The ADC has takes just a voltage value from a as a feedback and gives 16 bits digitize value as the output. Whatever voltage value I measure on the board using the voltmeter I can calculate it using the 16 bits on my screen (teraterm).[image]
3. My apparatus consists analog feedback signal then i am using ADC to digitize the value now I have to apply FIR filter to remove the noise, Now I am not sure which noise the noise which added up in the analog signal from the environment or some sort of noise comes there due to ADC ?
   Well the voltage which is coming from the Wheatstone bridge is that is affected by some type of noise, if yes how can decide the frequency cutoffs to remove the noise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reason's you will see a lot of noise with this circuit:

1. No anti-aliasing filter. You HAVE to put an analog filter (even a simple RC filter) before the ADC to filter out frequencies higher than your [nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). If you don't do that, noise on these higher frequencies will alias down to every other frequency you look at and mess up your signal.
2. You are using a differential ADC but you are not putting in a differential signal (you just tied the negative pin to your voltage reference). Also, almost every differential ADC requires that the average of the voltages at the +/- pin ALWAYS fall within a small range, and your ADC is no different (the ones I've worked with just go haywire if you don't). Look at [the datasheet for your ADC](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/adc161s626.pdf). Figure 48 has a setup identical to what you are trying to do -- use that setup and you'll be fine

One last note, as a direct answer to your question, selecting a frequency for your filter completely depends on the frequencies you are interested in. True noise is "white" and will have components across all frequencies. The best you can do is to filter out every frequency you are not interested in to get rid of as much noise as possible. If that's not good enough, you have deeper problems.

Comment: There is an analog filter also which is already there. Now about the frequencies: As you are saying there will be noise in all the frequency components but I need to decide what are the cutoffs of the FIR filter I am going to make as I guess making a filter with -ve dB gain value for all the frequencies is not practical i think. There is paper in which they have decided a filter and it's cutoff but how did they decided the cutoffs of FIR I am not able to understand that part. http://www.theaccents.org/ijacr/papers/current_sep_2013/12.pdf Please refer to the link, in part 4.1 page 82.

Comment: Now I just had an idea that I can just make a low pass pass filter with cutoff like 50Hz or 200Hz, if possible less 20Hz. I think thats all I can do ?

Comment: can you confirm that what I wrote in the above comment is correct or not ?

Comment: Yes, if all you are interested in is the DC (0 Hz) component of the signal a 20 Hz filter will knock out almost all of your noise.